# What is a stable way to create an angled div like this image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a section like this, I have done similar with psuedo elements going in one direction but never to a point like this , wondering if there is a better more stable way (work in ie)? there will be content in the blue section as well.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to just import the image as a jpg, set the z-index so that it is far behind the rest of the document, make sure the display property takes it out of the flow, and then just build your content inside of the image. Example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
    <img style="z-index: -10; position: absolute;" src="./FMbOL.jpg">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Hello Hows it going</p>
    <p>Hello How are you!</p>
</div>

</html>
```

This code produces this

https://gyazo.com/7df23ebdcde8f1b01e46ff3e6912f46c